# How to get data from a promise (async/await) and use it `outside` the promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

So I await for the promise to fulfil, then I want to use the resulting data *outside* of `.then()` or the `async` function.

```
function HomeScreen() {

    const userData = async () => { 
        await AsyncStorage.getItem("user_nicename")     
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>      
            <Text>Hello, { userData() } </Text>  //*I want to use it here for example*//

            <Button 
                style={styles.buttonLogin}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}
                title='Logout'
            />      
        </View>
    ) 
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

of course my code will throw an error because `userData()` is a 'promise object'. I just want the string value, which I have no problems accessing *inside* `.then(data => ... )`. But how do I access it outside so I can use it somewhere else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That's a poor duplicate @Samathingamajig

Comment: Use states and then use it where ever you want, unless you want to use it globally, in that case learn about Global States

Comment: userData() returns the entire promise cycle

Answer (score 2):

You to use `useState` and `useEffect`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function HomeScreen() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            setUserData(await AsyncStorage.getItem("user_nicename"));
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>      
            <Text>Hello, { userData } </Text>

            <Button 
                style={styles.buttonLogin}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}
                title='Logout'
            />      
        </View>
    ) 
}

export default HomeScreen;
```